# How to specify a subfolder as destination for a project's DLL in clickonce?

Tags: deployment, prism, clickonce

We have a WPF project, with prism. We are loading dynamically some modules, which are basically put in a subfolder(PrismModules).

The application works fine, but now if we try to deploy it with ClickOnce, it ignore the Output path structure and put everything in the root folder instead of our "PrismModules" subfolder. Then the application doesn't load those modules.

Is this a limitation of ClickOnce deployment?

**EDIT**

To give a little bit more information, here is how is structured the solution:

```
Solution 
 - WpfClient
 - PrismModules
   - Module A
   - Module B
   - Module C
```

They are all built in the same root directory, the Module A/B/C are just in the subfolder `PrismModules`.

WpfClient doesn't reference any of the modules, it scans the folder `PrismModules` at runtime and load all Dll containing an implementation of `IModule`.

What I did notice:

Some DLL that are referenced are put on the root(and not in `PrismModules` folder), and the ones that are only dynamically loaded, are not even present(we cannot set anything for them in the ClickOnce menu.

Answer (score 0):

In your main project (which is deployed by ClickOnce) create a subfolder PrismModules and add to it dlls of your modules *as links*.  Set "BuildAction" to Content and "Copy to Output Directory" to "Copy Always".

Create a subfolder PrismModules under WpfClient and add links to it.  Take the dlls from their output location (whatever is the output location of ModuleA, ...)

Make an additional check: under Deploy/Application Files those added dlls should be marked as "Included" and not as "Data Files".  Usually VS does it right however.

Set build order on your solution correctly: WpfClient should depend on your Module X so that you were not able to deploy new version of application with old dlls.

Step-by-step:

Build all projects (in Release).

Standing on WpfClient, right-click select "Add new folder", name it PrismModules.

Standing on newly created PrismModules, right-click select "Add Existing Item".  Navigate to the module dll you built, wherever it is located.  Instead of "Add", press "Add As Link" (note the triangle to the right of "Add").

Comment: But my dll are projects that are just built in this directory

Comment: Do not understand your project structure.  Can you explain?

Comment: What i don't understand: If I update my DLL, it means that I've to copy them again? Will it work in debug?

Comment: Nothing changed for debugging - it will work as it worked before.  To reiterate: do not change the output dir of your modules.  Add the LINKS to new folder.

Comment: What are "links"? How do you create them?

Comment: @J4N Updated the answer.